# Rails 3: add sum column to the result hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this models:

```
Event
has_many :incidents
```

and

```
Incident
belongs_to :event
```

I want to getting all events with the incident numbers for each one in one query. In Rails I know exist "group by" and "sum" methods but I don't know how mix both.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a left join, group by object id and count elements:

```
Events.joins('LEFT JOIN incidents ON incidents.event_id = events.id').group_by('events.id').select('events.*, COUNT(incidents.id) AS incidents_count')
```

You could also look into counter_cache option.